HTTP request not returning an observable? Browser throwing error: 'You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected'
I have some logic that requires 2 nested API calls - so I decided to use switchMap. But the app doesn't think the second API call is an observable. The project lives in a monorepo, but the weird thing is that the code executes fine on the other projects...
Error:

You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, ReadableStream, Array, AsyncIterable, or Iterable.

Here is a simple use of switchMap that I'm trying to run on my project
const { http } = this;
const url = `URL1`;

http.get<any>(url).pipe(
  switchMap(res => {
    console.log('call 1 finished')
    return http.get<any>('URL2')
  }),
).subscribe(val => {
  console.log('successful operation', val);
})

The subscription never executes. But if I wrap the second http call in of, the code will pass but the subscription output (val) is an observable.
Any other reasons (angular project setup, http interceptors) that could cause this? There is also some AngularJS code/downgrade code being run at start
Using Angular 18 and RXJS 7.
Update: Was able to convert it to a promise to get it to pass.
    this.http.get('https://catfact.ninja/fact').pipe(
      switchMap( (res) => {
        return lastValueFrom(this.http.get('https://catfact.ninja/fact'));
      }),
    ).subscribe((val) => {
      console.log('Final output2:', val);
    });

I think there's an issue with the Observable object on my project. Any rxjs operators that take in observables (switchMap, forkJoin) are throwing errors when I put in the http request. Converting it to a promise seems to bypass this. I'll have to take a deeper look. Thanks everyone for helping.

just my personal wild guess, maybe the reference of this in the 2nd obs call is pointing somewhere different?
if all else of ur debug attempt failed, i think u could  still take advantage of the of by replacing ur current pipe with:
swtichMap(res1  => of(http.get<any>('URL2')), swtichMap(obs2 => obs2)

Why do you need the type assertion to <any>? The Angular HTTP client's get() request returns an observable, so there must be some issue with the resolution of the function. Check if the correct get() function is triggered. If not you'd need to provide more code to find the issue. Try to access this.http.get() without <any> assertion for both requests instead of destructing it out of this.

@Jordan the problem lies somewhere else, please try to replicate the issue on stackblitz and update on the question

Update, was able to finally get to the value from the API with using lastValueFrom. Still unsure what's causing my issue, but I think this solution is fine for now
     switchMap( (res) => {
       return lastValueFrom(this.http.get('https://catfact.ninja/fact'));
     }),
   ).subscribe((val) => {
     console.log('Final output2:', val);
   });```
